# How to Create list of filenames in an S3 directory using pyspark and/or databricks utils

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I have a need to move files from one S3 bucket directory to two others. I have to do this from a Databricks notebook. If the the file has a json extension, I will move into jsonDir. Otherwise, I will move into otherDir. Presumably I would do this with pyspark, and databrick utils (dbutils).

I do not know the name of the S3 bucket, only the relative path off of it (call it MYPATH). For instance, I can do:

```
dbutils.fs.ls(MYPATH)
```

and it lists all the files in the S3 directory. Unfortunately with dbutils, you can move one file at a time or all of them (no wildcards). The bulk of my program is:

```
for file in fileList:
  if file.endswith("json"):
    dbutils.fs.mv(file, jsonDir)
    continue
  if not file.endswith("json")
    dbutils.fs.mv(file, otherDir)
    continue
```

My Problem: I do not know how to retrieve the list of files from MYPATH to put them in array "fileList". I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code runs if you do these minor changes:

```
fileList = dbutils.fs.ls(MYPATH)
for file in fileList:
  if file.name.endswith("/"): # Don't copy dirs
    continue
  if file.name.endswith("json"):
    dbutils.fs.mv(file.path, jsonDir + file.name)
    continue
  if not file.name.endswith("json"):
    dbutils.fs.mv(file.path, otherDir + file.name)
    continue
```

Here, `file.name` is appended to keep the name of the file in the new dir. I need this one Azure dbfs backed storage, otherwise everything gets moved to the same blob.
It is critical that `jsonDir` and `otherDir` ends with a `/` character.

Comment: did you change your original answer? That one worked for me! Well, except it included the directory in the list. Also I had errors in my other code above which I have since fixed (and edited post to reflect). Either you changed yours or someone else removed their answer. Very confused on how to proceed. Again, previous answer worked except for including directory. Plus, I updated my code above.

Comment: Yes, I did change my answer because I was pretty sure that you would need the `+ file.name`. You can access all of the edits by pressing the `edited xx hours ago` link in my answer. I will keep the current answer because it provides a complete solution, but please comment if some part of it did not work for you.

Comment: Here is the solution from fskj that worked for me. It is the solution that will work against the current post status (edited Oct 8th at 15:22)  fileList = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls(MYPATH)]

Comment: Weird, I definitely need the `+ file.name`. But I'm testing this is on Azure, so the semantics on S3 might be different.